# Creating a model of the S-Curve in Sonic the Hedgehog?

Tags: modeling, mathematics

I'm really sorry that I have to ask such a full-on question, but I'm kinda new to Blender and I'm using it for a school project. As part of it, I'm trying to create an object/mesh that looks like this:
[image: S-Curve in Sonic]

I'm thinking it would be something like two rotated cubic functions but I'm really not quite sure. If anyone would help me out, I'd be very grateful.

Thanks!

Comment: Please add more details. What exactly are you trying to create? When you say "something like this" do you mean a tube in an S shape? Or do you mean a volume with a tunnel going through it? Be more specific and detailed, otherwise people won't be able to help.

Answer (score 0):

I have one possible solution if you don't want to model bezier/path by controls (even though it's pretty easy... ) firstly I recommend to you to activate this addon that is already in Blender -> Edit -> Preferences -> Addons :
[image]

After this you can make more default objects:
[image]

Out of there you can select Arc curve
and set it like this at the bottom left window:
[image]

You will get half circle curve and you can set type of curve as well, the you can simply duplicate it, rotate it:
[image]

Lastly, select joints you want to merge, press F and use RMB and select:
[image]

This is easy way withou need to manually rotate your curve but you will still need to tweak it to be exactly how you want it

After you have your curve, go to curve properties and give it some depth:
[image]

Or you can use some object